# what is the best way to write the 4 possibilities of 2 conditions in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, control-flow

CONDITION1 AND CONDITION2 are String variables which can be NULL or NON NULL.
Say for example i have 2 variables like CONDITION1 AND CONDITION2.
If CONDITION1 is not NULL, then i call METHOD1() and if it returns TRUE then i check if CONDITION2 is NOT NULL and then i call METHOD2().
If CONDITION1 is NULL, then i check if CONDITION2 is NULL or not. If it is not NULL then i call METHOD2().
If CONDITION1 is NOT NULL, then i call METHOD1() and then i check if CONDITION2 is NULL or not. If it is  NULL then i DONT call METHOD2().

BOTH methods return a boolean value. TRUE or FALSE.

1. If None of them are NULL
2. If CONDITION1 is NOT NULL and CONDITION2 is NULL
3. If CONDITION2 is NULL and CONDITION1 is NOT NULL
4. If both conditions are NULL

Below is the Code using if else if statements.

IS THERE A BETTER WAY TO DO IT ?

`//Fail` and `// process further` represent the same code.

```
       if(CONDITION1 != null && CONDITION2 != null){
            if(METHOD1()){
                if(METHOD2()){
                    // process further
                }else{
                    //Fail
                }
            }else{
                //Fail
            }
        }else if(CONDITION1 != null && CONDITION2 == null){
            if(METHOD1()){
                // process further
            }else{
                //Fail
            }
        }else if(CONDITION1 == null && CONDITION2 != null){
            if(METHOD2()){
                // process further
            }else{
                //Fail
            }
        }else{//Both are NULL
            // process further
        }
```

Comment: It is not typical for boolean values to be nullable. Please explain your use case more specifically.

Comment: Do all your `//Fail` represent the same code? Do all your `// process further` represent the same code?

Comment: Condition1 and 2 are String variables whic can be null or non null. Yes...//FAIL and // process further represent same code.

Comment: Typing words with capital letters does not make your text more readable

Comment: Please stop shouting at us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as all your `// process further` represent the same code, and all your `//Fail` represent the same code, as you say, then what you're doing is the equivalent of:

```
if ((CONDITION1==null || METHOD1())
    && (CONDITION2==null || METHOD2())) {
    // process further
} else {
    // fail
}
```